# Skip an empty sequence inside a LINQ .Where statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of *Tuple **arrays*** like this:

`(Type, Func<int, bool>)[][] Formats;`

I also have a `Type typ` and a `int i`.

I then need an `IEnumerable<(Type, Func<int,bool>[])>` (aka return items) where a potential match is evaluated by `Item1` (i.e. `Type`) matching `typ` in the format `.IsAssignableFrom(typ)`. If we get a match, then we aren't done: we only include it if `Item2.Invoke(i)` evaluates to true.

`var results = Formats.Where(f => f.Where(o => o.Item1.IsAssignableFrom(typ)).First().Item2.Invoke(i));`

This is not valid because I think if a return item doesn't have an inner item to retrieve in the `.First()` call, it throws an `InvalidOperationException` "Sequence contains no data" because you can't call `.First()` on an empty sequence.

Can you help restate this Linq to ignore the sequence if empty?

Comment: This is what `FirstOrDefault()` is for. Use that instead of `First()`, and then ignore items where that method returns `null`.

Comment: You might want to look into the NULL-conditional Operator. https://dev.to/pushpk/using-null-conditional-and-coalescing-operators-in-c-1186

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect opportunity to use the [`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-6.0):

> Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if no element is found.

In this case, the "default value" would be `(null, null)`. So, use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `First()`, and then ignore items appropriately. Something like this might work:

```
var results = Formats.Where(f => f.Where(o => o.Item1.IsAssignableFrom(typ)).FirstOrDefault().Item2?.Invoke(i) ?? false);
```

Comment: thank you, that was the boost in the right direction I needed.